# store columnwidth in cookies

Tags: cookies, extjs, grid

I am using extjs grid and want to store the order and width of the columns for the users.
I have added:

```
var dateExpires = new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*300);
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
expires: new Date(dateExpires) //300 days from now
}));
```

Now is the order of the columns stored but still missing the size for the columns. I don't use forcefit because i saw that could be an issue.

This is how a column look like

```
{
 xtype: 'gridpanel',
 id: 'GridPanel',
 titleCollapse: false,
 store: 'gridStore',
 stateId: 'gridPanelState',
 region: 'center',
 viewConfig: {},
 columns: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'vehicle',
                        text: 'Vehicle'
                    },

                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'speed',
                        text: 'Speed'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'routeId',
                        text: 'RouteId'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'direction',
                        text: 'Direction'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'description',
                        text: 'Description'
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using? Usually if you specify `stateId` for the grid it will save all information about columns. Do you have that?

Comment: i use 4.1.0-gpl. I have the stateId set but it is not stored

Comment: Do you see in list of cookies your information?

Comment: It doesn't have your stateId... and it should...

Comment: i found the cookie with the stateId:
o%3Acollapsed%3Db%253A0%5Eflex%3Dn%253A1%5Ecolumns%3Da%253Ao%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah1%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah2%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah3%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah4%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah5%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah6%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah7%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah8%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah9%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah10%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah11%255Eo%25253Aid%25253Ds%2525253Ah12

Comment: Then it should be saving. How do you configure your grid? I mean where do you define columns etc?

Comment: i edit the code with how i made the grid using architect